# Problems dsplaying Windows VM on Virtualbox on 22.04 with Wayland

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, 22.04

I had created on Ubuntu 14.04 a Windows 10 VM that has followed me till today with no problem. This week-end, I have upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 beta (from 20.04). I have seen that I can't use anymore the Windows 10 VM. The screen stays black, and if I hover the screen, the VirtualBox menu turns to somewhat torn white tape…
[image: Strange white menu on black screen]

When I manage to open the tasks on Ubuntu (by using moving slowly three fingers upwards on the touchpad) I can see Windows running "normally".
[image: Windows 10 seems to run OK on tasks]

My mouse is then not at all usable on VirtualBox. To stop the VM, I need to open the tasks (as shown above), click the "X" button to open the VirtualBox quit menu on the VM, select "Power off the machine" (sending the shutdown signal doesn't do anything) and type the Enter key, as the mouse doesn't work.

I have created a simple Ubuntu 22.04 VM without any problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello. Since 22.04 does not exist yet there is no support available for it on this site. Sorry.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Also don't forget it's still in *testing* with *beta* freeze just *hit* & *beta* release on 31-March-2022

Answer (score 1):

Switching to X11 should fix this issue.

You can do this at the login screen, clicking on the gear icon and selecting `Ubuntu on Xorg.`

### Long answer

This issue is related to the Wayland display server.

In previous Ubuntu versions (ex. 14.04), the display server was X11. On Ubuntu 22.04, Canonical replaced X11 with Wayland.

While most applications work correctly on Wayland, sometimes you can find visual glitches like what you are experiencing.

Switching back to X11 should fix your issue without any side effects on your system. Wayland's main reason is code maintainability - in theory, there's no difference between X11 or Wayland to the final user.